# Select active data by order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have 2 tables `posts` and `categories`, There is `one-to-many` relation between both tables.

Here are the two tables:

```
                     posts table
_________________________________________________________________
| id | title | content | category_id | post_order  | post_active |                                        
|____|_______|_________|_____________|_____________|_____________|
| 1  | test1 | testing |     1       |       0     |      1      |
| 2  | test2 | testing |     1       |       1     |      1      |
| 3  | test3 | testing |     2       |       2     |      0      |
| .  | ..... | ....... |     .       |       .     |      .      |
|____|_______|_________|_____________|_____________|_____________|


       categories table
_____________________________________
| c_id | c_name | c_order | c_active |                                       
|______|________|_________|__________|
|   1  |  cat1  |    0    |    1     |
|   2  |  cat2  |    1    |    1     |      
|   3  |  cat3  |    2    |    0     |  
| .    | .....  | ....... |    .     |      
|______|________|_________|__________|
```

There is a relation between `category_id` and `c_id`, So that the `category_id` in the `posts` table refers to the category id `c_id`.

The `post_order` and `c_order` are used to order both `posts` and `categories`.

And the `post_active` and `c_active` are used to define if it would be displayed for the users or not, `1` means yes it will be displayed, While `0` is no.

I show the `categories` and the `posts` are beneath them like:

```
________________________________________
|                 |          |          |
|    cat1         |   cat2   |   cat3   |
|  (active)       |__________|__________|
|                                       |
|                                       |
|    test1                              |
|        testing                        |
|                                       |
|    test2                              |
|        testing                        |
|_______________________________________|
```

The code to display the data:

```
//That query should get the active categories and posts ordered by the order column, Not sure if it's correct. 
$results = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.c_id = posts.id WHERE categories.c_active = '1' and posts.post_active = '1' order by categories.c_order, posts.post_order ASC");

//Execute the previous query.
$results->execute();

while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $categories[$row['category_name']][] = $row;
}

//Print the categories
foreach (array_keys($categories) as $category_name) {
    echo $category_name;
}

//Print the posts
foreach ($categories as $category_name => $posts) { 
    foreach ($posts as $post) { 
        echo $post['title'];
    }
}
```

There is HTML code inside the previous PHP code for creating tabs and accordion for each post, If that would help, Here is the full code:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <?php foreach (array_keys($categories) as $category_name) { ?>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $category_name); ?>" aria-controls="<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $category_name); ?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $category_name; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul> <!-- .nav-tabs -->

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category_name => $posts) { ?>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $category_name); ?>">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"> 
                <?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#<?php echo $post['id']; ?>_faq" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#<?php echo $post['id']; ?>_faq">
                                    <?php echo $post['title'] ?>
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="<?php echo $post['id']; ?>_faq" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <?php echo $post['content']; ?>
                            </div> <!-- .panel-body -->
                        </div> <!-- .panel-collapse -->
                    </div> <!-- .panel-default -->
                <?php } ?>  
            </div> <!-- .panel-group -->
        </div> <!-- .tab-pane -->
    <?php } ?>
</div> <!-- .tab-content -->
```

I should get all the active `categories` and `posts`, But I only get the first active category with its posts ordered.

Comment: Are you sure your query is the updated one?

Comment: Your query looks wrong: `SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.c_id = posts.id` should be `SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN posts ON categories.c_id = posts.category_id`

Comment: That's the query now `SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN posts ON c_id = posts.category_id WHERE category_active = 1 AND posts.post_active = 1 ORDER BY category_order  AND posts.post_order ASC`

Comment: But I still get the one category only

Comment: an aside: in the `ORDER BY` replace `AND` with `,`; and `ASC` is not required.  Can you build us a dbfiddle.com demo that we can play with?  It is always simpler to provide support when the issue is all tee'd up and ready to code on.

Comment: I changed it to `SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN posts ON c_id = posts.category_id WHERE category_active = 1 , posts.post_active = 1 ORDER BY category_order , posts.post_order`, But I get an error `near ' posts.post_active = 1`

Comment: `category_order` isn't a column in your table.  Use `c_order`.  Also, you don't need to designate a table name for `post_active` because there is no naming conflict (mysql will know what you are seeking).

Comment: @mickmackusa, Here you are http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bfa7

Comment: Still the same error `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax near ' post_active = 1 `

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bfa7/2 (`AND` was meant to stay in the `WHERE` clause)  What needs to be done from here?

Comment: @mickmackusa, In this case if I have 3 categories and 10 posts, I will get the `category_name` 10 times not 3

Comment: Because as you see, I show the categories at the top inside `<ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll recommend this query:

```
SELECT b.c_name, a.id, TRIM(a.title) AS title, a.content
FROM posts a
INNER JOIN categories b ON a.category_id = b.c_id
WHERE a.post_active = '1' AND b.c_active = '1'
ORDER BY b.c_order, a.post_order
```

- Rather than asking php to trim the title, just fix it up within the query.
- I am using `INNER JOIN` because I expect all rows in `posts` will have a corresponding row in `categories`.
- Order by `c_order` then `post_order` so that categorical entries are grouped together when you iterate the resultset.

Based on my demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ca1a1/3

And referencing `fetchAll`'s [FETCH_GROUP](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_GROUP)...

```
$resultset = fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
/* should generate:
    $resultset = [
        "social" => [
            ["id" => 5, "title" => "fifth title", "content" => "fifth content"],
            ["id" => 4, "title" => "fourth title", "content" => "fourth content"],
            ["id" => 2, "title" => "second title", "content" => "second content"]
        ],
        "tech" => [
            ["id" => 1, "title" => "first title", "first content"]
        ]
    ];
*/
```

Your categories are in `array_keys($resultset)`.

And you can iterate the prepared resultset and access the first level keys and the subarray rows to display the data.

Comment: Thanks that's worked well as usual, The code becomes `$results->execute();
$results = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
foreach (array_keys($results) as $category_name) {
    echo $category_name;
}
foreach ($results as $category_name => $posts) { 
    foreach ($posts as $post) { 
        echo $post['title'];
    }
}`

Answer (score -1):

**Your query must be like this:**

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` `p`
LEFT JOIN `categories` `c` ON `c`.`c_id` = `p`.`category_id`
WHERE `c`.`c_active` = '1'
    and `p`.`post_active` = '1'
order by `p`.`post_order`, `c`.`c_order`
```

**Then execute query and put in array **

```
$myArr = array();
foreach($youQuery as $key => $val){
    $myArr[$val->c_id]['c_id '] = $val->c_id;
    $myArr[$val->c_id]['c_name '] = $val->c_name;
    $myArr[$val->c_id]['post '][$val->id]['id] = $val->id;
    $myArr[$val->c_id]['post '][$val->title ]['title ] = $val->title ;

    $i++;
}
```

Then you can loop array like you want.

Comment: You misspelled `foreach`.  Why have you declared `$i` or `$key`?  For the record, none of those backticks are necessary.  The spacing in your keys and missing single quotes has ruined your snippet.

Comment: Just remove, what you think wrong, i just make example for you.

Comment: No thanks.  I'll allow you to tidy up your own post.